# How to start QEMU on Windows with monitor enabled?

Tags: windows, debug, qemu

I've downloaded the latest 64-bit version of [QEMU for Windows](http://qemu.weilnetz.de/) and it installed fine. However, I now have problems switching to Monitor mode when trying my code. The documentation says Ctrl-Alt-[1, 2, 3] switch between the display modes, but it doesn't work for me.

I run `qemu-system-i386 -fda test.bin` (where test.bin is a simple bootsector initializer) and all I get is the main VGA window. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seemed to be with my choice of QEMU binaries for Windows. Downloading [this](http://lassauge.free.fr/qemu/) version instead solved the problem.

Binary files can then be launched with the following syntax: `qemu-system-i386 -fda test.bin -M pc -boot a`